# maintenance-page--offline

Tags: 8, maintenance-mode

In Drupal 7, we could create maintenance-page--offline.tpl.php to be shown during database failures. I want to create this page for D8 as well, however maintenance-page--offline.html.twig does not get picked up. Does anyone have an idea what the template name should be in D8?

Comment: The name is correct, see [system_theme_suggestions_maintenance_page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21system.module/function/system_theme_suggestions_maintenance_page/8.4.x)

Comment: But this template doesn't work, see this issue https://www.drupal.org/node/2720109